# How to manually visit 500 error page in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I know that Phoenix can handle the error response and render the related error page. But I would like to visit the `500.html.eex` manually by `http://localhost:4000/500.html`. Is there any good way to do it instead of add new controller?

The reason I do this, is that I have js method to check stuff, and redirect to error page if failed.

Cheers

Comment: I think you cannot unless you add a route to it.

Comment: _“redirect to error page if failed”_ this sounds as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why would you show `500` in such a case? How would you set the HTTP Response Code to be `500`? Showing `500` error page with a status `200` is kinda wrong.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Oh, thanks dude to tell me the conception of XY Problem. That's exactly what I usually do. Yeah, indeed, I want to redirect to a custom error page when js checking failed, and I thought the 404/500 error page is the most common page and people may have more thoughts on it and easily understand.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of temporarily viewing the 500 error page, to test it and such, I would tweak the program to redirect 404 errors to the 500 page by customising `MyApp.ErrorView`.

In this module, just change (or add):

```
def render("404.html", _assigns) do
    ...
end
```

to this:

```
def render("404.html", _assigns) do
    render("500.html", assigns)
end
```

Then, in `config/dev.exs` change the web endpoint configuration so that `debug_errors` is set to `false`:

```
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  # http: [port: 8000],
  debug_errors: false
```

Then proceed to a random url: `localhost:8000/somerandomurl` to view your `500.html` error page.

Here, your `500.html.eex` page should show. Let me know if you require a more complex tweak.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the controller and route for it, so that you can just redirect to that URL.